# When considering vector space, do I need to define multiplication and addition of the scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have some vector space, say $V$; vectors $\bf v, u$ such that $\bf v,u$ are in $V$; and some scalars, call them $k,c$

So, if I understood this correctly, following operations

$$\tag 1 \mathbf{u} + \bf v$$

and

$$\tag2 k\bf u$$

*do not* necessarily mean usual addition or usual multiplication. In other words, when talking about vector space above, firstly we should **define** those two operations.

But what about these?

$$kc$$

$$k + c$$

Do these two operations mean usual scalar addition and usual scalar multiplication? Or should they be defined before considering vector space too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalars come from a field.   So there is already a notion of addition and multiplication.

Comment: So in other words, for example, if we have field which consists of real numbers, then the scalars will behave *exactly* like the real numbers, correct? (for example $kc = ck$, $k +c = c+ k$, $k (a + b) = ka + kb$ etc.)

Comment: Yes.  Correct.  Perhaps review the definition of a field:  a commutative ring in which all the nonzero elements are units.  Or look up "field axioms ".

Answer (score 2):

You take the scalars from a field, so addition and multiplication of scalars are already defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you define vector space you define it over one field $F$.
This field is a set of your scalars.
All that you need to prove is that your scalar multiplication was defined as $ku \in V$, and your addition was defined with the same property $v + u \in V$. And after it you can prove that your $V$ follows properties of vector space.
Notice that in vector spaces nobody cares about $k + u$ if $k \in F$ and $u \in V$. As an example, bring as $V=R^2$ and as $F=\mathbb{R}$. Of course $R^2$ is a vector space. But what is $u + k = (a,b) + k$? This operation is not defined in the definition of vector space.